# Shapes Problem in Tensorflow MultiClass Classification

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a multi-class text classification using keras tensorflow for 5 classes. This is the shape of the data after cleaning, tokenizing and padding and this is the final data sizes:

```
Training Data is:  (1424,)  and  (1424,)
Validation Data is:  (356,)  and  (356,)
Testing Data is:  (445,)  and  (445,)
```

I created the model with this structure which is very simple and I am using the input size as 1000 which is the padding sequence maxlen:

```
model = Sequential()
input_dim = training_sequences.shape[1]
model.add(Embedding(input_dim= 1000, output_dim=512, input_length=input_dim))
model.add(Dense(64 ,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5 ,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= "Adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I train the model using

```
InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node Equal
 (defined at C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\mytf_env\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py:3609)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_9096]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node Equal:
In[0] Cast_1 (defined at C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\mytf_env\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py:716)  
In[1] Cast_2 (defined at C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\mytf_env\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py:3607)
```

any advice?

Comment: What's the output of `input_dim.shape`

Comment: @Djinn the shape is 1000

Comment: Can you update your question with how you defined your training data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding layer output is not a 1D output, so you might need to use a flatten layer after the embedding layer
write this as your model architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
input_dim = training_sequences.shape[1]
model.add(Embedding(input_dim= 1000, output_dim=512, input_length=input_dim))
model.add(flatten())
model.add(Dense(64 ,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5 ,activation='softmax'))
```